# continuous (on 3, 4 and 5) f is constant, if $f(x+2)+f(4x)=f(2x+1)+f(2x+2),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function that is continuous on 3,
>   4 and 5, such that $f(x+2)+f(4x)=f(2x+1)+f(2x+2),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that f is constant.

I don't know what to do here!! I think that we may be able to prove that f is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, but then what? Also, I don't have any school knowledge of sequences, but only some calculus, including integrals, derivatives, IVT, MVT, EVT, Rolle, Fermat, Darboux, limits and such things.

Any hint of a proof that doesn't use Taylor or sequences?

Comment: Also, we haven't been taught the epsilon-delta definition of a limit...

Comment: What do you mean, "continuous on $3,4,5$"?

Comment: @lulu I mean continuous on points A(3, f(3)), B(4, f(4)) and C(5, f(5)).

Comment: And no assumption at any other values?  Interesting.

Comment: @lulu Yes, it is... But I think that may be due to the fact that we have exactly 3+1=4 terms on the equality.

Comment: Just a thought.  I think the idea is that you can show it is constant on all Q and if f(x) = then f(qx) = c for all rational q. If it's continuous at 3, then it must be constant on an interval of around 3 and those constant on all q x the interval for all q = all the reals.  But that only needs it to be continuous at one point.

Comment: @lulu 's question, I think there may be a mistake in setting the problem.  Continuity at 2 is necessary and sufficient to force continuity, and continuity at other points is irrelevant. The statement is false, but a similar statement with 3,4,5 replaced by 2 is true.    Any nonconstant function with f(x)=f(2x-2) satisfies the more complicated functional equation in the problem, and there exist such functions that are continuous everywhere except x=2.

Comment: Can anyone here think of any counter-example or prove it finally?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false. Continuity at $2$ is necessary and sufficient for the function to be constant.  Continuity at **all** $x \neq 2$, which is more than what is assumed in the problem, is not sufficient for the function to be constant.

The functional equation is

$(T^2 + D^2) f = (TD + DT) f$,

or equivalently, $(T - D)^2 f = 0$, where

- $D$ is the doubling operator $f(x) \to f(2x)$  and
- $T$ the translation operator $f(x) \to f(x+1)$.

First we solve $(T-D)g = 0$.  This says $g(x+1) = g(2x)$ or $g(2+t)=g(2+2t)$.  The solution is any function $g$ invariant under the transformation $2+t \to 2+2t$. The only solutions continuous at $2$ are $g = $ constant.  There are nonconstant solutions continuous everywhere except at $2$, which shows that the conclusion of the problem is incorrect even for the stronger functional equation $f(x)=f(2x-2)$ that implies the 4-term equation in the problem.

Next, to solve the 4-term functional equation, we want $g = (T-D)f$ to be a solution of $(T-D)g = 0$.  The functions $f$ making that true are exactly the functions linear in $n$ along geometric progressions $(2 + 2^n a)$.  The linear function can be any $P(a) + nQ(a)$ where $P$ and $Q$ are arbitrary functions of $a \in [1,2)$.

Continuity at points other than $x=2$ is not enough to force the function to be constant, or to have $Q=0$, or to have $P$ or $Q$ be constant.

Answer (score -1):

Denote $g(x) = f(2x) - f(2x-2)$. Then given condition implies that $g(x) = g(2x-3)$ and $g$ is continuous at $x_0=3$. Now suppose, there exists $y<3$ such that $g(y)\neq g(3)$. Set $a$ = $\limsup_{g(y)<g(3), y<3} y$. Because $g$ is continuous at $3$, such $a$ exists. However, $g(3-\epsilon) = g(3-2\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon>0$. Contradiction. So $g$ is constant.  Now only you need to show that $g(x) = 0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: We haven't been taught anything from sequences, sup and inf.

Comment: Do you mean $g(x)=f(x+2)-f(2x+2)$? That would give $g(2x-1)=f(2x+1)-f(4x)$, so that the equation becomes $g(x)=g(2x-1)$.

Comment: are you suggesting that $2(x+2) - 1 = 2x+1$?

Comment: $g(x)=f(2x)-f(2x-2)$ does not give $g(x)=g(2x-3)$.

Comment: Maybe he means g(x)=f(x)-f(2x-2).   But the problem statement is still false if one requires g(x) = f(x) - f(2x-2) = 0 everywhere (which would make the 4-term functional equation true) and f(x) continuous everywhere except at x=2.   @almagest